# Finding average datalength for field of datatype IMAGE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which stores DOCUMENTS as image datatype. I wish to find the average size of all the documents in the table. I am running the following query

```
select AVG(DATALENGTH(document)) from DOCUMENT
```

document is the field of datatype image. I am getting the following exception

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

Please help me resolve this error?

Comment: Do you really have images that are larger than the maximum integer (2 Gbytes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried casting the DATALENGTH(document) to an int manually?

```
AVG(CAST(DATALENGTH(document) as BIGINT))
```

Edit: Changed casting to BIGINT due to jpw's suggestion.

Comment: Since the AVG function is overflowing the INT type casting to it shouldn't help, and the DATALENGTH function returns INT for IMAGE anyway, but casting to BIGINT might solve it as that would force the average function to use the larger data type.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `Convert/Cast Image datatype to Varbinary(max)`. According to **[MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx)**, `Datalength()` function returns int for image data type where as bigint for varbinary(max).

```
Select Avg( Datalength( Convert(Varbinary(max), document) ) ) 
From DOCUMENT
```

[Please read the following note from MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

> ntext , text, and image data types will be removed in a future version
>   of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.
>   Fixed and variable-length data types for storing large non-Unicode and
>   Unicode character and binary data. Unicode data uses the UNICODE UCS-2
>   character set.

Comment: Will surely talk to my DBA and bring this to his notice